# How do I set a default merge strategy specific to a file with Git?

Tags: git, merge, git-merge, branching-strategy

*This question is not iOS-specific, but I'm including the actual use case here for clarity*

I run an iOS project called `Foobar`, obviously kept under version control.
Amongst the project files in the iOS project environment there's something called `Foobar-Info.plist`, an XML file which stores interesting information about the project, like versions and the number of builds I've made.

Every time I build the project, I increment the build count stored in to this file like so:

```xml
...
<key>BuildCount</key>
<string>2203</string>
<key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
<string>0.0.4</string>
<key>CFBundleVersion</key>
<string>0.0.4-release/0.0.4.2203</string>
...
```

where '0.0.4-release' is a git-flow branch name, and 2203 is a build number. This is used in the `CFBundleVersion` field, so that it's really obvious to me where the build came from.

Imagine in another branch, I've made a lot of progress since the release and the same fields look like:

```xml
...
<key>BuildCount</key>
<string>2754</string>
<key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
<string>0.0.4</string>
<key>CFBundleVersion</key>
<string>0.0.4-feature/add-quux-and-baz.2754</string>
...
```

Let's say I'm done with release, and it's merged into the mainline `develop` branch.

#### The problem

In order to get the latest changes made in the release branch, I want to rebase the feature branch onto `develop`.

when this happens, `Foobar-Info.plist` will cause a conflict at *every commit* in the rebase process. This is because the build numbers will have incremented for every commit; I must **manually merge by choosing the lines manually specify** the lines with the latest version. Note that the base version of the 3-way diff will *also* be different.

```xml
<string>2000</string>  // Base
<string>2754</string>  // Local   ** always pick this one; it's the latest
<string>2203</string>  // Remote
```

How can I tell Git that for one specific file, `Foobar-Info.plist`, I want it to resolve my conflicts for me by taking the *latest* change?

The file must be kept under source control. I want to keep the `BuildCount` because it's a cool indication of effort put into my project and I want to keep it! I know that the figure only indicates the *minimum* number of builds done, but that'll be good enough for me.

Comment: I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/928646/how-do-i-tell-git-to-always-select-my-local-version-for-conflicted-merges-on-a-s, which could be an answer to my question.

Comment: 'Copy merge' ISN'T what I want. I sort of want a COPY MERGE FOR CONFLICTS ONLY. Other changes should still be applied and merged as normal.

Comment: Another thing: it's not copy merge because the latest change is *not necessarily* the local branch: it's conceivable that `develop` has commits from other features, which has a greater build number from the branch being rebased.

Comment: I also found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7607125/git-merge-conflict-to-always-take-the-newest-file
they wrote their own merge driver to handle their case.

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is a late answer, but if I understand your question, what you're looking for is a [`.gitattributes`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes) file.

You can specify merge strategies for specific files or folders with relative paths from the `.gitattributes` file, which looks like this:

```
* text=auto
path/to/your/file.plist merge=union
```

Comment: merge=union combines both versions so you end up with 
 <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
 <string>100</string>
 <string>101</string>