# git: How do I add a custom merge strategy?

Tags: git, merge

I'm trying to add a custom merge strategy similar to the one in this question: [Git merge conflict to always take the newest file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7607125/git-merge-conflict-to-always-take-the-newest-file)

I've saved the script as `git-merge-latest.sh` and added the following lines to `.git/config`:

```
[merge "latest"]
    name = select latest file merge driver
    driver = git-merge-latest.sh %O %A %B
```

However, when I run `git pull --strategy latest`, I get the message:

```
Could not find merge strategy 'latest'.
Available strategies are: octopus ours recursive resolve subtree.
```

I've tried checking `git config merge.latest.driver`, which returns the expected output. I also changed the value of `driver` to `true` just to verify that it wasn't a problem with finding the script.

This happens on two different systems running git 1.8.2.2 and 1.7.9.5. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

In this case, you didn't configure a *merge strategy*, you configured a *merge driver*:

A merge strategy is a program that determines how two (or more) *commits* are merged.  By default, `git merge` uses the "recursive" strategy, found in the program `git-merge-recursive`.  By specifying the `--strategy <strategy>` flag to `git-merge` (or `git-pull`) you tell it to invoke a different strategy.  If you want to plug in your own merge strategy, you can, by creating an executable `git-merge-mystrategy` in your path and running `git merge --strategy mystrategy`.

This is different than a *merge driver*.  A merge driver is the mechanism used to resolve a conflict on a file that exists when merging two commits.  You plug in your own merge driver in the manner you outlined, by configuring a `merge.mydriver.driver` setting.

To enable your merge driver for a particular file, you need to configure the driver for that file in [`.gitattributes`](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes.html):

```
filename merge=mydriver
```

Comment: Might want to explicitly state that adding a merge strategy is a matter of modifying the `git` code - it isn't something that can be done through configuration changes (at least currently)...

Comment: @twalberg - you can plug your own quite easily, actually; if you have a `git-merge-xyz` in your path then git will run it if you `git merge --strategy xyz`.  I will make that more clear in my answer.

Comment: Is the specification for how to write a git merge strategy executable documented anywhere? What should I expect on stdin, and what should be the output?

Comment: Any way to set a default strategy for certain files?

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin From the [link](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_defining_a_custom_merge_driver) in the answer: “The merge driver is expected to leave the result of the merge in the file named with %A by overwriting it, and exit with zero status if it managed to merge them cleanly, or non-zero if there were conflicts.” You can specify which arguments are passed to your executable through percent variable substitution.

Comment: @AntonStrogonoff You gave documentation about merge drivers, but Asad Saeeduddin asked about merge strategies.  For merge strategies, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47454227/how-to-configure-a-merge-strategy .