# Force git custom merge driver for the purpose of merging pom.xml (maven) files

Tags: git, maven, merge, pom.xml

I've got a custom git merge driver configured for **pom.xml** (Maven) files.

**The configuration:**

The **.gitattributes** file:

```
pom.xml merge=pommerge
```

And the **.gitconfig** file:

```
[merge "pommerge"]
    name = A custom merge driver for Maven's pom.xml
    driver = mergepom.py %O %A %B
```

This works great for resolving conflicts in this kind of file. Unfortunately this doesn't solve all or problems for **pom.xml** files.. This driver is only called while merging if and only if the **pom.xml** is changed in both the main branch (so, the branch in which we call 'git merge otherbranch') and the branche we'd like to merge ('otherbranch').

We'd like to **always** use our merge driver for pom files, even if the pom file is only changed in 1 branch and can be be merged without conflicts.

Is there a way to force our custom 'pommerge' driver in this situation?

**Update**
I've tried almost anything, but without luck. I even checkout out the git source code and added more logging to the code and installed/MAKE'd it to check if I could find out if there was a specific extension point I could use somehow.
But the code is pretty hard to understand in which cases which path in the code is followed, so this effort produced more frustations than solutions;)..

The only way I can make it to work, which is not a solution, is to change the file at both ends (branches), before merging.. But this is not very user friendly

I still hope someone comes up with a genius solution or clue which helps me get a little bit further with this challenge.

Thanks you all for your time!

Comment: Could you do something with a git hook, maybe a pre-commit hook that runs mergepom.py on the file if it's modified?

Comment: @WilliamHilton Is the pre-commit hook called while merging? Because the file may be changed and committed: only while merging the file should be partially reverted (specific branch settings).

Comment: OK, I'm stumped. I tried playing around with .gitattributes  to mark pom.xml as binary, but still couldn't force git to create a "conflict" when merging branches when the file was only changed on one branch.

Comment: @WilliamHilton thx for trying! That's also what I encountered unfortunately..

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a custom merge *strategy*, and you have defined a merge *driver*.

A driver is called only on conflicts, while a strategy is used anytime two commits are merged.

See this answer for how to set up your solution:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23140455/6084013