# Git - how to force manual merge even if there is no conflict

Tags: git, merge

This is a question which was asked many times over the years. I have found a number of answers, in particular this one:

[Git - how to force merge conflict and manual merge on selected file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074452/git-how-to-force-merge-conflict-and-manual-merge-on-selected-file) (@Dan Moulding)

This page contains is a detailed guide how to set up a merge driver that would always return failure and thus make possible a manual merge. I have tried to adapt that solution for Windows:

1. I added the following to my `%homepath%\.gitconfig`:

   `[merge "verify"]
        name = merge and verify driver
        driver = %homepath%\\merge-and-verify-driver.bat %A %O %B`
2. I changed the driver to

   `cmd /K "echo Working > merge.log & git merge-file %1% %2% %3% & exit 1"`

   (`echo Working > merge.log` was added to check whether the driver was invoked).
3. and, at the root of the repo, created a file `.gitattributes` with the following line:

   `*.txt  merge=verify`

Unfortunately, it does not work. I tried to merge a file, `feature.txt`, and, alas, the merge completed successfully. It seems that the driver was not invoked at all, since the merge.log file was not created.

Do I do anything wrong? Any solution to the problem of forcing manual merge is most welcome.

Comment: As an aside, in case you can't get the merge driver to work, you can always amend the merge commit via `git commit --amend`, after making the changes you want.  Not perfect, but it would at least give you an immediate workaround until you sort out the scripting mess.

Comment: Thank you, @Tim. Unfortunately, it does not answer our needs. I want to be able to start a 3-way merge even if Git thinks it's not needed. I am trying to persuade ClearCase users to move on to Git. In ClearCase it's just a matter of checking a checkbox before starting a merge, and users will be surprised that such an option is not available anymore.

Comment: Is it so that what your colleagues think they need it to select by the time of merge which changes they want to apply? This operation is not very good because git's own bookkeeping relies on fact that all changes are merged at once, you cannot merge some changes and keep rest for later. Basically this is what is another case of [evil merge](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1461909/2303202) which reverts some  changes. It could make sense in some cases but used carelessly would cause the "where did my edits go" issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tl;dr: I tried to repeat what you described and it seems to work. There were 2 changes compared to yours version but without them I have merge failed as well (because driver basically failed to run)

I have tried this:

Create a merge driver `$HOME/bin/errorout.bat`:

```
exit 1
```

Create a section for the merge type

```
[merge "errorout"]
   name = errorout
   driver = ~/bin/errorout.bat %A %O %B
```

Create the .gitattributes file:

```
*.txt merge=errorout
```

After that, error is reported as I think you want it to be reported:

```
 $ git merge a

 C:\...>exit 1
 Auto-merging f.txt
 CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in f.txt
 Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

I have git version 2.11.0.rc1.windows.1. I was not able to make the complicated command as you specified run successfully, it was reporting some syntax errors.

Comment: Alas, it did not work for me. Following explanation of @torek, I think that the merge driver was not invoked at all. Did you try to change a file on one branch only, so that obviously there would be no conflict, and then run the merge?

Comment: I did not understand that you need it to fail even when the change is only at one side. Then yes mergedriver is not going to help.

Comment: OK, now I understand. Everything works fine, and the driver is invoked, but only if both _ours_ and _theirs_ are different from the _base_. This actually solves my problem, because only in this situation developers may insist on a manual merge. Thanks to max630 and @torek for the help.

Answer (score 8):

There are two parts to the problem.  The relatively easy one is writing the custom merge driver, as you did in steps 1 and 2.  The hard one is that Git doesn't actually bother *running* the custom driver if, in Git's opinion, it's not necessary.  This is what you have observed in step 3.

So, when *does* Git run your merge driver?  The answer is fairly complicated, and to get there we have to define the term *merge base*, which we'll get to in a moment.  You also need to know that Git identifies files—in fact, pretty much everything: commits, files, patches, and so on—by their *hash IDs*.  If you already know all of this, you can skip directly to the last section.

#### Hash IDs

Hash IDs (or sometimes *object IDs* or OIDs) are those big ugly names you see for commits:

```
$ git rev-parse HEAD
7f453578c70960158569e63d90374eee06104adc
$ git log
commit 7f453578c70960158569e63d90374eee06104adc
Author: ...
```

Everything Git stores has a unique hash ID, computed from the contents of the object (the file or commit or whatever).

If you store the *same* file *twice* (or more), you get the same hash ID twice (or more).  Since each commit ultimately stores a snapshot of every file as of the time of that commit, each commit therefore has a copy of every file, listed by its hash ID.  You can in fact view these:

```
$ git ls-tree HEAD
100644 blob b22d69ec6378de44eacb9be8b61fdc59c4651453    README
100644 blob b92abd58c398714eb74cbe66671c7c3d5c030e2e    integer.txt
100644 blob 27dfc5306fbd27883ca227f08f06ee037cdcb9e2    lorem.txt
```

The three big ugly IDs in the middle are the three hash IDs.  Those three files are in the `HEAD` commit under those IDs.  I have the same three files in several more commits, usually with slightly different contents.

#### Getting to the merge base: the DAG

The *DAG*, or **D**irected **A**cyclic **G**raph, is a way of drawing the relationships between commits.  To really use Git properly, you need at least a vague idea of what the DAG is.  It's also called the *commit graph*, which is a nicer term in some ways since it avoids specialized informatics jargon.

In Git, when we make branches, we can draw them in any number of various ways.  The method I like to use here (in text, on StackOverflow) is to put earlier commits on the left and later commits on the right, and to label each commit with a single uppercase letter.  Ideally, we'd draw these the way Git keeps them, which is rather backwards:

```
A <- B <- C   <-- master
```

Here we have just three commits, all on `master`.  The branch *name* `master` "points to" the last of the three commits.  This is how Git actually finds commit `C`, by reading its hash ID from the branch name `master`, and in fact the name `master` effectively stores *just* this one ID.

Git finds commit `B` by reading commit `C`.  Commit `C` has, inside it, the hash ID of commit `B`.  We say that `C` "points to" `B`, hence the backwards-pointing arrow.  Likewise, `B` "points to" `A`.  Since `A` is the very first commit, it has no previous commit so it has no back-pointer.

These internal arrows tell Git about the *parent commit* of each commit.  Most of the time, we don't care that they are all backwards, so we can draw this more simply as:

```
A--B--C   <-- master
```

which lets us pretend that it's obvious that `C` comes after `B`, even though in fact that's quite hard in Git.  (Compare with the claim "`B` comes before `C`", which is very easy in Git:  It's easy to go backwards, because the internal arrows are all backwards.)

Now let's draw an actual branch.  Suppose we make a new branch, starting at commit `B`, and make a fourth commit `D` (it's not clear exactly *when* we make it but in the end it doesn't matter anyway):

```
A--B--C   <-- master
    \
     D   <-- sidebr
```

The name `sidebr` now points to commit `D`, while the name `master` points to commit `C`.

One key Git concept here is that commit `B` is on *both* branches.  It's on `master` *and* `sidebr`.  This is true for commit `A` as well.  In Git, any given commit can be, and often is, on many branches simultaneously.

There's another key concept hidden in Git here that is quite different from most other version control systems, which I will just mention in passing.  This is that the actual *branch* is actually formed *by the commits themselves*, and that the branch *names* have almost no meaning or contribution here.  The names merely serve to find the *branch tips*: commits `C` and `D` in this case.  The branch itself is what we get by drawing the connecting lines, going from newer (child) commits back to older (parent) commits.

It's also worth noting, as a side point, that this weird backwards linkage allows Git to *never, ever change anything about any commit*.  Note that both `C` and `D` are children of `B`, but we didn't necessarily *know*, back when we made `B`, that we were going to make both `C` *and* `D`.  But, because the parent doesn't "know" its children, Git did not have to store the IDs of `C` and `D` inside `B` at all.  It just stores the ID of `B`—which definitely *did* exist by then—inside each of `C` and `D` when it creates each of `C` and `D`.

These drawings that we make show (part of) the *commit graph*.

#### The merge base

A proper definition of merge bases is too long to go into here, but now that we've drawn the graph, an informal definition is very easy, and visually obvious.  The *merge base* of two branches is the point at which they first *come together*, when we work backwards as Git does.  That is, it's the first such commit that's on *both branches*.

Thus, in:

```
A--B--C   <-- master
    \
     D   <-- sidebr
```

the merge base is commit `B`.  If we make more commits:

```
A--B--C--F   <-- master
    \
     D--E--G   <-- sidebr
```

the merge base remains commit `B`.  If we actually make a successful merge, the new merge commit has *two* parent commits instead of just one:

```
A--B--C--F---H   <-- master
    \       /
     D--E--G   <-- sidebr
```

Here, commit `H` is the merge, which we made on `master` by running `git merge sidebr`, and its *two* parents are `F` (the commit that used to be the tip of `master`) and `G` (the commit that still *is* the tip of `sidebr`).

If we now continue making commits, and later decide to do *another* merge, `G` will be the new merge base:

```
A--B--C--F---H--I   <-- master
    \       /
     D--E--G--J   <-- sidebr
```

`H` has *two* parents, and we (and Git) follow both parents "simultaneously" when we look backwards.  Hence, commit `G` is the first one that's on both branches, if and when we run another merge.

#### Aside: cross merges

Note that `F` is not, in this case, on `sidebr`: we have to follow the parent links as we encounter them, so `J` leads back to `G` which leads back to `E`, etc., so that we never get to `F` when starting from `sidebr`.  If, however, we make our next merge *from* `master` *into* `sidebr`:

```
A--B--C--F---H--I   <-- master
    \       /    \
     D--E--G--J---K   <-- sidebr
```

Now commit `F` is on both branches.  But in fact, commit `I` is also on both branches, so even though this makes merges going both ways, we're OK here.  We *can* get in trouble with so called "criss cross merges", and I will draw one just to illustrate the problem, but not go into it here:

```
A--B--C--E-G--I   <-- br1
    \     X
     D---F-H--J   <-- br2
```

We get this by starting with the two branches going out to `E` and `F` respectively, then doing `git checkout br1; git merge br2; git checkout br2; git merge br1` to make `G` (a merge of `E` and `F`, added to `br1`) and then immediately also make `H` (a merge of `F` and `E`, added to `br2`).  We can continue committing to both branches, but eventually, when we go to merge again, we have a problem picking a merge base, because both `E` *and* `F` are "best candidates".

Usually, even this "just works", but sometimes criss-cross merges create issues that Git tries to handle in a fancy way using its default "recursive" merge strategy.  In these (rare) cases you can see some weird-looking merge conflicts, especially if you set `merge.conflictstyle = diff3` (which I normally recommend: it shows you the merge base version in conflicted merges).

#### When does your merge driver run?

Now that we have defined the merge base and seen the way hashes identify objects (including files), we can now answer the original question.

When you run `git merge branch-name`, Git:

1. Identifies the current commit, a.k.a. `HEAD`.  This is also called the *local* or `--ours` commit.
2. identifies the other commit, the one you gave via *`branch-name`*.  That's the tip commit of the other branch, and is variously called the other, `--theirs`, or sometimes *remote* commit ("remote" is a very poor name since Git uses that term for other purposes too).
3. Identifies the merge base.  Let's call this commit "base".  The letter `B` is also good but with a merge driver, `%A` and `%B` refer to the `--ours` and `--theirs` versions respectively, with `%O` referring to the base.
4. Effectively, runs two separate `git diff` commands: `git diff base ours` and `git diff base theirs`.

These two diffs tell Git "what happened".  Git's *goal*, remember, is to combine *two sets of changes*: "what we did in ours" and "what they did in theirs".  That's what the two `git diffs` show: "base vs ours" is what *we* did, and "base vs theirs" is what *they* did.  (This is also how Git discovers if any files were added, deleted, and/or renamed, in base-to-ours and/or base-to-theirs—but this is an unnecessary complication right now, which we will ignore.)

It's the actual mechanics of combining these changes that invokes merge drivers, or—as in our problem cases—doesn't.

Remember that Git has every object catalogued by its hash ID.  Each ID is unique based on the object's contents.  This means it can instantly tell whether any two *files* are 100% identical: they are exactly the same if and only if they have the same hash.

This means that if, in base-vs-ours or base-vs-theirs, the two files have the same hashes, then either *we* made no changes, or *they* made no changes.  If we made no changes and they made changes, why then, obviously the result of *combining* these changes is *their file*.  Or, if they made no changes and we made changes, the result is *our* file.

Similarly, if ours and theirs have the *same* hash, then we both made the *same* changes.  In this case, the result of combining the changes is either file—they're the same, so it won't even matter which one Git picks.

Hence, for all of these cases, Git simply picks whichever *new* file has a different hash (if any) from the base version.  That's the merge result, and there is no merge conflict, and Git is done merging that file.  **It never runs your merge driver** because there is clearly no need.

Only if all three files have three different hashes does Git have to do a real three-way merge.  This is when it will run your custom merge driver, if you have defined one.

**There is a way around this,** but it is not for the faint of heart.  Git offers not just custom merge *drivers*, but also [custom merge *strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23140240/1256452).  There are four built-in merge *strategies*, all selected via the `-s` option: `-s ours`, `-s recursive`, `-s resolve`, and `-s octopus`.  You can, however, use `-s custom-strategy` to invoke your own.

The problem is that to write a merge strategy, *you* must identify the merge base(s), do any recursive merging you want (a la `-s recursive`) in the case of ambiguous merge bases, run the two `git diff`s, figure out file add/delete/rename operations, and then run your various drivers.  Because this takes over the [whole megillah](http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-mag1.htm), you *can* do whatever you want—but you *must* do quite a lot.  As far as I know there is no canned solution using this technique.

Comment: Excellent explanation, @torek! Learned a lot from it.

Comment: (BTW, a similar situation exists in genealogy: it is very difficult to find a person's offspring because most documents mention a person's parents but not children.)

I wonder whether there is any other way to stop the merge before it completes (e.g., by _git merge --no-commit_) and somehow get the values of _base_, _ours_ and _theirs_. Then we could run _git merge-file_ with these parameters.

Comment: If you need to inspect changes when there are no conflicts you rather need [difftool](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-difftool) not a mergetool. You can find some which supports diffing the whole tree.

Comment: @JenniferPhilips: I like the genealogy analogy (two words that make a tongue twister of sorts). Meanwhile it might be good if custom Git merge drivers and/or file paths could be flagged as "always run if base ≠ branch-tips, even if the merge appears trivial", and that would fix it. Or, perhaps, if there's a custom merge driver, just treat it as "always run". (It's not clear to me whether, unflagged, it should run if ours = theirs yet ours and theirs ≠ base.)