# Migrating from Jenkins Ci Service to gitlab-ci.yml

Tags: jenkins, gitlab, gitlab-ci, git-merge

Until now we were using Jenkins to run our build on any feature branch based on the [Jenkins CI service](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/integration/jenkins.html). We are currently experimenting with pipelines based on gitlab-ci.yml.
As a starting point I would like to limit this only for specific branches that created by few developers as a beta test.

I was trying to avoid merge of  .gitlab-ci.yml from feature branches to release branches based on .gitattributes and merge strategies (see [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#_merge_strategies)), but this force me to have  .gitlab-ci.yml in the release branch. As result gitlab force me to have some valid yml content (I hoped I could at least keep it empty) otherwise  I will get invalid yml failure.

Any suggestion on keeping the .gitlab-ci.yml only on feature branch and avoiding manual steps to avoid the merge of .gitlab-ci.yml file until we will adopt it for all branches?

Similar questions:
https://forum.gitlab.com/t/how-to-ignore-gitlab-ci-yml-file-when-merging-the-branches/17948
[GitLab merge behavior - keep file from branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42720116/gitlab-merge-behavior-keep-file-from-branch)

Comment: You could just merge it but excluding the release branches by using `except: - branch-name`

Comment: This is a simple solution that may work, following your lead I was reading on rules https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rules (I am using version 12.3) maybe this will be better

Answer (score 0):

Following [Bertrand](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2614364/bertrand-martel) response and as I don't actually care to have the `.gitlab-ci.yml` in release branches as long as the pipelines execute only on selected merge requests. I changed my `.gitlab-ci.yml` to include a rule.
According to the logic below the pipeline will be executed only on merge request with the branch name format FTR-ddddd-g

```
image: maven-mta:latest
variables:
  GIT_DEPTH: 0
Unit tests and Sonar Check:
 script:
    - mvn clean verify sonar:sonar
  artifacts:
    reports:
      junit:
        - "*/target/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml"
  allow_failure: false
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME =~ /^FTR-\d+-gl/ && $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "master"'
      when: always
  tags:
  - sonarqube
  - docker
```

I got an unexpected side effect (which I actually like) on the merge requests meeting the criteria above the Jenkins CI Service is not running.
Unfortunately I didn't found any documentation supporting this behaviour and the following [page](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/enable_or_disable_ci.html) recommend to disable Jenkins CI when having gitlab ci.

Answer (score 0):

> "As a starting point I would like to limit this only for specific
>   branches"

you can use the only tag.

```
  only:
    - feature-*
```